# Sending multiple emails with data from rows in Talend Open Studio

Tags: talend, eai

I m working of a project of Enterprise application architecture using software **talend**
i have this table : **User(Id_user, name_user, Email)**
what i want to do is select Data from this table and sending email to each user using Tsendemail component 
i could so far make a connection to Database using **TMssinput** and send a single email using Tsendemail 
but i dont know how to select values of Row and use them as "email" for **Tsendemail** 

Can someone help me pls ? and thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As tSendMail component is not a processing component (ie, it cannot handles more than one vector in input) but a starting component, the best way to do so is to use the good-ol' tFlowToIterate [as we did here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334590/access-a-string-array-from-textractxmlfield-xml-tag-with-1-value). Your job will almost look like:

```
tMssInput---row---->tFlowtoIterate--->Iterate---->tSendEmail
```

Inside the tFlowToIterate instance you're going to put everything you need from `row` into the `globalMap`. Every data-processing operation should be done before that, on the `row` context (for example, filtering out users you won't the mail to be sent, etc.).