# In Talend, how do I store contents of a file into a variable

Tags: loops, import, talend

I have a file of unique numbers.  I want to import the file into a variable and then loop through each value to perform a task on.  I did this in Talend using an object variable but I can't seem to do this in Talend.
File is basically as follows
123455Z
12345DW
423213E
A343Ds3

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: What did you already try ? Please add a screenshot of your current job. You should probably begin with defining a metadata for your input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Tfiledelimitedinput > tmap > tfiledelimitedoutput

Perform the operation on the column in the tmap.

Don't forget you can change the delimiter of the file by ' ' if you want

Is that you are looking for ?

Comment: After importing the data, I then want to perform a tsoap on the using the first value (123455Z) in line 1 (I have this part) which will get me data to export. Then do the same for the next value (12345DW), etc. In the end, X number of lines in my file, I do X number of soap calls to get data and X number of files exported.  I'm just having problems storing my values and running a loop to do the tsoap/exporting part.

Comment: I think you'll need a tFlowToIterate to perform this kind of action : it will help you make iterating calls to your service. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334590/access-a-string-array-from-textractxmlfield-xml-tag-with-1-value

Comment: You are correct.  I did  tFlowToIterate --> iterate --> tFixedFlowInput.  Thanks Corentin.